# Docker database error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I'm creating an app using docker and laravel. At the beginning everything was fine, I ran the migrations successfully. But at some point an error occured while migrating and trying one of the routes on Postman:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = users and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }

      +33 vendor frames
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

My `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=33069
DB_DATABASE=users
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

`docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    users:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        environment:
            DB_HOST: db
            DB_DATABASE: users
            DB_USERNAME: root
            DB_PASSWORD: root
        command: 'php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0'
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        ports:
            - 8001:8000
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: users
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        volumes:
            - ./storage/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 33069:3306
```

`Dockerfile` :

```
FROM php:7.4

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        graphviz \

    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install sockets \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN composer install
```

I have no idea of what went wrong, the connection to database failed all of a sudden.
The credentials are right, I can enter the db container succesfully.
I have tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`.
Also I have tried to specify the socket path in `database.php` but nothing changed.

Comment: If you create project in another directory again, does it work? If so probably fastest solution is to do that, create db dump from current folder as you said it is accessible and import that dump into the project in new directory.

Comment: I tried once and the problem occured a bit later. I tried once again and no luck

Comment: DB_PORT - should it be not 3306? at least I have 3306 in my example. If changing it does not help, please add all files so we can reproduce locally minimally. Or better - give us github or similar repo, so we can just clone and reproduce.